# Как реализовать функцию Sleep в методе execute в VK API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

Использую метод `execute` в VK API. Как реализовать часть кода `//ожидать 2сек`. В целом программа должна проверять, не появился ли новый пост на свет.

```
var posts = API.wall.get({"count": 1,"owner_id":-143352091,"offset":1});
var post = posts.items[0];
var id=post .id; //Получаем id поста до задержки

//ожидать 2сек

var posts_2 = API.wall.get({"count": 1,"owner_id":-143352091,"offset":1});
var post_2 = posts_2.items[0];
var id_2=post_2.id; //Получаем id поста после задержки
var text_2=post_2.text;

if (id !=id_2) {
 return {"text": text_2};
 } else{return {"text": null};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никак, execute не поддерживает паузы. 
Да и в целом на wall.get довольно жесткие лимиты(https://vk.com/dev/data_limits), так что ежесекундно проверять ничего не получится.

Стоит посмотреть в сторону callback API, возможно он подойдет для вашей задачи.

Comment: Посмотрел в документацию callback API, я так понял что этим методом могут пользоваться только владельцы группы, обычные потпищики не могут, или я где то ошибся?

Answer (score 0):

Я нашёл очень интересный костыль: запрос [podcasts.searchPodcast](https://dev.vk.com/method/podcasts.searchPodcast) с короткими строками, по необъяснимой причине, выполняется очень медленно.

Пример запроса [execute](https://dev.vk.com/method/execute):

```js
return API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"a","count":1000});
```

Этот запрос у меня выполняется целых 6 секунд.
Конечно, это не функция `sleep` (уже [сказали выше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/801217/418625), что нет такого), но, если критически важно сделать задержку, то можно использовать. Не рекомендую добавлять такой код в реальный продукт, потому что VK может изменить время работы / заблокировать метод.

---

Я спросил у VK по поводу использования этого метода:

> Если будут нагрузки, мы примем меры.

Поэтому, я считаю, можно использовать этот запрос только для каких-либо внутренних тестов.