# Как ускорить хранимую процедуру (execute) с большим числом запросов к VK API?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vkscript

У меня в моём приложении, что бы не попасть в лимит по количеству запросов, используются хранимые процедуры (метод execute). Но, при тестировании, обнаружил, что некоторые запросы к API могут выполняться несколько секунд, из-за чего тормозится вся работа в целом (немного дольше, чем бы этого хотелось).

Пример типичной процедуры:

```js
return {
  "friends": API.friends.get({...}),
  "groups": API.groups.get({...}),
  "messages": API.messages.get({...})
  // В среднем 10 запросов в таких процедурах
}
```

Может есть какая-то возможность ускорить всё это? И, желательно, оставить всё так же, в execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, такая возможность есть. VK добавили возможность *многопоточности* в запросах [`execute`](https://dev.vk.com/method/execute). И делается это очень легко:

```js
var res1 = fork(API.friends.get({...}));
var res2 = fork(API.groups.get({...}));
var res3 = fork(API.messages.get({...}));

return {
  "friends": wait(res1),
  "groups": wait(res2),
  "messages": wait(res3)
}
```

### Как это работает?

При создании такого `fork()` моментально возвращается `fork_id` (число), по порядку, начиная с 1. `wait()` уже принимает число и возвращает ответ от VK API. Если передать несуществующий `fork_id` будет соответствующая ошибка. Всего `fork()` может повторяться 25 раз (затем ошибка), поэтому не получится сделать запросов [свыше ограничений](https://dev.vk.com/api/api-requests#%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

### Правда работает быстрее?

Коротко: **да**, в некоторых ситуациях: **в разы быстрее**.
Синтетический пример: (медленный запрос взят из [другого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/801139/418625)).

```js
var a = API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"a"});
var b = API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"б"});
var c = API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"в"});


return [a, b, c];
```

3 разных запроса выполняются ~14 секунд.

```js
var a = fork(API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"a"}));
var b = fork(API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"б"}));
var c = fork(API.podcasts.searchPodcast({"search_string":"в"}));

return [wait(a), wait(b), wait(c)];
```

3 таких же запросов выполняются ~5 секунд. Существенная разница!

### Почему в [документации](https://dev.vk.com/method/execute) ничего об этом не сказано?

<s>В последнее время документация в принципе редко обновляется. Публичная версия *5.131* стоит пару лет, когда офф. приложения VK используют *5.200* и выше</s> ([update](https://dev.vk.com/ru/reference/versions): Апи начало обновляться). Эту особенность я нашёл сам, она используется в некоторых запросах в web версии клиента VK. Возможно это какая-то внутренняя особенность. Я считаю, что документацию просто не обновили, так как это работает для всех приложений / токенов.